# How to display static html page with image on Heroku

Tags: html, url, heroku

I'm trying to display an html page on Heroku that has an image tag. The image exists but I cannot figure out what path to use so that it can be found. I keep getting 404 errors with every absolute path I try, and I can't use a relative path, because it appends it to the place the html page was loaded from (which happens to be /api/errorcodes/x where x is a number that is used to find the original html page)  I.E.

```
app.get('/api/errorcode/:errorcode', function(request, response) {
   var errorcode = request.params.errorcode;
   var doc = 'Error' + errorcode + '.html';
   console.log('__dirname = ', __dirname);
   response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/pages/' + doc);
});
```

So the directory structure is as follows:

views/pages/Error1.html
views/pages/Error1.fld/img001.png

And Error1.html has `<img src="/views/pages/Error1.fld/img001.png">` and returns 404 (The page Error1.html loads, but the image gets a 404 in the heroku logs).

I have also tried "/app/views/pages/Error1.fld/img001.png" as well as moving the image to /public and trying the same combinations from there. How do I tell the img tag where to find the image?!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured this out. In case anyone else comes across this here is the answer:

Before declaring any routes, add the `static` middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

"The `static` middleware has the same effect as creating a route for each static file you want to deliver that renders a file and returns it to the client" - excerpt from O'Reilly's Web Development With Node & Express book.

Then in the html file you can use `<img src="/img/logo.png">` if your image file is at `public/img/logo.png`.